# how to change the volume of the media player via main activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, android-mediaplayer

I use c# xamarin and I ran into a problem, I use backGround music and I want to control its volume with a seek bar, but I have a couple of problems, the music is an Intent.
and I have written a method in the background music class to set the volume, but I can't access it because the music is an intent.
here is the background music class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Arkanoid
{
    [Service]

    class backgroundMusic : Service
    {
        public ISharedPreferences sp;
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public void SetVolume(int vol)
        {
            mp.SetVolume(vol, vol);
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            sp = this.GetSharedPreferences("details", FileCreationMode.Private);
            int volume = sp.GetInt("backgroundMusic", 50);
            base.OnCreate();
            mp = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.backgroundMusic);
            mp.Looping = true;
            mp.SetVolume(volume, volume);
        }
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            int volume = sp.GetInt("backgroundMusic", 50);
            mp.SetVolume(((float)volume)/100, ((float)volume)/100);
            int position = sp.GetInt("position", 0);
            mp.SeekTo(position);
            mp.Start();
            return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = sp.Edit();
            editor.PutInt("position", mp.CurrentPosition);
            editor.Commit();
            mp.Stop();
            mp.Release();
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

    }
}
```

here is the way I start the music, in the main activity, inside OnCreate

```
         bMusic = new Intent(this, typeof(backgroundMusic));
         StartService(bMusic);
```

and here is the problem:

```
 private void Music_ProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            vMusic = e.Progress;
             //missing code here
        }
```

where I wrote "missing code here" is where I need to change the volume of the music.
also, because I wrote the StartService(bMusic) in the OnCreate, it restarts the song every time i go to on create, which I don't want, I want it to keep on running as long as the app is running, and only me changing the volume via the seek bar.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **AudioManager** to control the music volume.

```
private AudioManager audioManager;
private int maxVolume, currentVolume;
Intent bMusic;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        ...

        bMusic = new Intent(this, typeof(backgroundMusic));
        StartService(bMusic);
        audioManager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(AudioService);
        maxVolume = audioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume(Stream.Music);
        SeekBar seekBar = FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.seek);
        currentVolume = audioManager.GetStreamVolume(Stream.Music);
        seekBar.Max = maxVolume;
        seekBar.Progress = currentVolume;
        seekBar.ProgressChanged += SeekBar_ProgressChanged;
    }

private void SeekBar_ProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        audioManager.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Music, e.Progress, 0);

    }

protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        StopService(bMusic); // you need call stopService then it will call the OnDestroy method of your service,then it will save the currentposition,and next time it will continue the music.
    }
```

Comment: so let me add some things so you will understand me more. I want the music to be played at all times when the app is running, and on the main activity I open a custom dialog, and there is the seek bar to control the volume, I want the volume to be changed when I change the progress of the seek bar, and not the sound of the phone, so what we need to do is to start the music the first time the app runs, then we need to control its volume via the seek bar, but never stop the music, even when the main activity is destroyed and the music should be on when I am in different activities.

Comment: You could try to define a interface,then implement it in your service.